# OpenGL ES/real time/position of any vertex that is displayed?

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, geometry, feedback, vertices

I'm currently dealing with OpenGL ES (2, iOS 6)… and I have a question

i. Let be a mesh that has to be drawn. Moreover,

ii. I can ask for a rotation/translation so that the point of view changes.

So,
how can I know (in real time) the position of any vertex that is displayed?

Thank you in advance.

jgapc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what it is you are after, but if you want to know *where* your object is after doing a bunch of rotations and translations, then one very easy option, if you perform these changes in your program code instead of in the shader, is to simply take the entire last row or column of your transformation matrix (depends if you are using row or column major matrices) which will be the final translation of your object's *center* as a coordinate vector.

This last row or column is the same thing as multiplying your final transformation matrix by your object's local coordinate center vector, which is (0,0,0,1).

If you want to know where an object's vertex is, rather than the object's center, then multiply that vertex in local coordinate space by the final transformation matrix, and you will get the new coordinate where that vertex is positioned.

Comment: Upvote for suggesting the clever last row/col trick. However, as extensive discussion revealed, OP wanted the transformed vertices.

Comment: As I noted, the transformed vertices can also be achieved the same way, the math is just slightly more complicated since the vertices are not at the origin.

Comment: Thanks Herr Bach for your detailed answer. That is smart. But this implies that I have to postmultiply all vertices (since I don't know what vertex is displayed (or abour to be)) and then deal with all data- even if 1% of the shape is currently displayed. Am I right?

Comment: Using this method you would indeed need to do some vertex multiplications in your code and look at them. Alternately, if you use a scenegraph and/or octree-type organization of objects, you could manage information about what is actually visible that way, but it might be more intense than you need right now. (Many graphics/games engines employ these techniques).

Comment: Thanks, I will follow your maths. To avoid slow computation, maybe could I split the mesh into subsets and order them (on screen, adjacent= about to be, off screen). I'll come to more intense code when I'm ready for it.

Comment: anything to filter out vertices you don't need to process is a good thing. google "octree" also for some context worth knowing about.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I'd like to point out:

1. Back-face culling *discards triangles*, not vertices.
2. Triangles are also *clipped* so that they're within the viewing frustum.

I'm curious as to **why** you care about what is not displayed?

Comment: Thank you Rahul for having replied, and for your precision! I have edited my question so that what I'm aiming to is clear.

Comment: You're welcome @jgapc! I don't know about only the displayed vertices, but you could always multiply them by the ModelviewProjectionMatrix. Caveat: you should generate it yourself. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1679/_index.html). After transforming them, normalize the result (divide each of `x`, `y` and `z` by the fourth coordinate `w`). Once you've done this, you can do a simple "check 2D bounds" test to see if they're within your view frustum.

Comment: Another thing... OpenGL ES 2.0 does not have transform feedback (where you can get the post-transform vertex data). See [this](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/176553-Transform-Feedback-Alternative-in-gl-es-2).

Comment: Thanks for the doc. It's always good to keep track of what is deprecated ;) I guess your suggestion is the most straightforward thing to do. It's just a kind of bit frustrating to think that the GPU «knows" what is on display and is off the screen… but not me, unless I implement a test to figure it out ( if p(x,y,z)=(y,z)< Bound then etc.).

Comment: Yeah, it seems that way. Unless it's top-secret, mind sharing what you're trying to achieve? There *might* be a simpler way to solve your original problem...

Comment: [About the forum: thanks… it's a kind of definitive answer: OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't keep track of what I'm looking for…]
No it's not secret actually. It's a video game. I have a volume (say a cube) and the finger make it rotate/translate. the design patern is the following one: 
1) I keep track of the displayed vertices
2) I have an event (roughly speaking: finger in (x, y, z) ) 
if the finger points a vertex i.e the two positions (finger and vertex matc) something happen- kind of Rubik's cube, actually.

Comment: So you want to prevent the cube from going off-screen? Just prevent your cube from going beyond the extents of an axis-aligned bounding box in world coordinates. Simply make sure that your camera sees all of that box, and you're done!

Comment: I think you're on track. Transform the vertices yourself and compare 2D coords against mouse coords. All the best! Btw, if this was helpful, I'd appreciate an upvote ;)

Comment: I don't have the sufficient amount of reputation to make an upvote… but I did appreciate your help and kindness :)